# Lottery win predictor

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python and I think I need some help with my program. Any kind of help or advice would be appreciated:)

You can see the program below, when I run it it gets stuck on the part of comparing the random ticket with the winning ticket(`win_combination`).

```
from random import choice

#Winning ticket
win_combination = input("Enter the winning combination of 4 numbers(1-digit-numbers): ")
while len(win_combination) != 4:
    if len(win_combination) > 4:
        win_combination = input("Reenter a shorter combination(4 one-digit-numbers): ")
    elif len(win_combination) < 4:
        win_combination = input("Reenter a longer combination(4 one-digit-numbers): ")

print(f"Winning combination is {win_combination}.")

#Specifying range of numbers to choose from
range = range(0, 10)

#Making a fake comparison-ticket to start of the loop
random_ticket = [0, 0]
random_ticket_string = f"{random_ticket[0]}{random_ticket[1]}{random_ticket[2]}{random_ticket[3]}"

#Params for the loop
n_tries = 0
n_guesses = 1

while random_ticket_string != win_combination:
    while n_tries > 4:
        random_ticket.clear()
        number = choice(range)
        random_ticket.append(number)
        n_tries += 1
        n_guesses += 1

    random_ticket_string = f"{random_ticket[0]}{random_ticket[1]}"
    
    if random_ticket_string == win_combination:
        chance_to_win = f"{(1 / n_guesses) * 100}%"
        print("Estimated percent to win is " + chance_to_win + ", it took " + f"{n_guesses} to match the winning combination.")
    else:
        n_tries = 0
```

Comment: did you mean `while n_tries>4:` to be `while n_tries<4:` ?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What happens when you run this?   Can you please show the sample input and the expected output as well as the actual output?

Comment: `random_ticket=[0,0]` is only of length two, whereas you look for up to length four.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, they are appreciated and I finally got it working.